# canInitWithRequest method in custom NSURLProtocol class is not triggered when using Alamofire

Tags: alamofire

I have a custom NSURLProtocol class to provide test data while I'm experimenting with Alamofire, but it doesn't seem to be used when making requests via the Manager request method.

This request goes through and returns a result just fine, but does not trigger canInitWithRequest:

```
    NSURLProtocol.registerClass(DBDummyURLProtocol)

    class MyURLRequestConvertible : URLRequestConvertible {
        var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
            return NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "cnn.com", path: "/")!)
        }
    }
    var myURLRequestConvertible = MyURLRequestConvertible();
    Manager.sharedInstance.request(myURLRequestConvertible)
```

If I use a simple NSURLConnection, the canInitWithRequest method is called as I expected:

```
    NSURLProtocol.registerClass(DBDummyURLProtocol)

    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "cnn.com", path: "/")!)
    NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate:nil, startImmediately:true)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should this work with Alamofire?

Answer (score 19):

Alamofire uses `NSURLSession` internally which does not respect the protocol classes registered using `NSURLProtocol.registerClass()`. Instead it uses a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object which has a `protocolClasses` property.

Unfortunately this configuration cannot be changed since the session always returns a copy and the property is not writable.

What you can do instead is create your own instance of `Alamofire.Manager` and pass it a custom `NSURLSessionConfiguration`

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.protocolClasses.insert(DBDummyURLProtocol.self, atIndex: 0)
let manager = Manager(configuration: configuration)

manager.request(.GET, "http://example.com")
```

Comment: Worth clarifying that `NSURLSession.shared` does absolutely respect protocol classes registered using `registerClass(_:)` however, sessions created using any initializer methods (i.e. not the shared session) do not. The latter is what Alamofire uses, and that's why it ignores `registerClass(_:)`.

Comment: I'm was trying to find out how this was done as well and how [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) supports Alamofire without needing control over the `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. Turns out, OHHTTPStubs does the same thing, via [method siwzzling](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/blob/826a9217fcd468220d154ed0075cbc1a20d0c5c9/OHHTTPStubs/Sources/NSURLSession/OHHTTPStubs%2BNSURLSessionConfiguration.m).